# "ERROR [22018] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Error in assignment" in parameterized ODBC query for sql type CHAR

Tags: c#, database, db2, odbc, db2-400

**Following is the code using parameterized query to query a DB2-i (DB2 for iSeries) database.**

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connStrSb.ToString());
conn.Open();
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText= "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 >= ?";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ss", "View_Status_Code");
var x = cmd.ExecuteReader();
x.Read();
```

Here **col1 is CHAR FOR BIT DATA**

The above code throws the following exception:

```
ERROR [22018] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Error in assignment.
```

**Following is the code using normal query (without parameters):**

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connStrSb.ToString());
conn.Open();
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 >= 'View_Status_Code'";
var x = cmd.ExecuteReader();
x.Read();
```

The above code works fine and returns a resultset.

Comment: Why did you try compare 2 chars with `>=` ? That sounds a bad idea to me..

Comment: That was a requirement.

Comment: Even "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 = ?" does give the same exception